# What emails are equivalent to each other?

Tags: email

I am trying to detect if the destination of the email is someone that is in the database. The problem is that there are equivalent emails and so a direct compare wont catch all cases. Some examples: `foobar@gmail.com` == `foo.bar@gmail.com` == `foobar+123@gmail.com`. Is there somewhere where these patterns are defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are referencing is "[Subaddressing Samantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Common_local-part_semantics)"

As far as most people are concerned: No, there aren't any additional rules you are not aware of. This is because both the "." and "+/-" are domain-specific identifiers.

Gmail chose to recongize emails with dots the same as those without, e.g. JohnSmith@gmail.com == John.Smith@gmail.com, because it makes it too easy for imposters. Therefore, we are guaranteed that all Gmail addresses will be the same with or without dots, but this guarantee does not extend to every other domain.

Answer (score -3):

If you mean to ask if there's a generic way of deciding this from the name alone, then no.  Even if you used patterns to find similar email addresses, how do you know they belong to the same person?  Maybe foobar123 really is different from foobar?

Now if your database tables have email addresses linked to people, you could use queries to find the people to whom they are linked and compare those.

The only other thing I can think of would be if you could do an IP lookup for email addresses, but there are a host of problems with that.

Comment: the examples i gave are pattern based. any email is equivalent to another with a period somewhere in the username. the same goes for the username followed by a plus with any string after that. I dont know whether this is a google thing or email in general though, i havent tested that. ip lookups mean nothing for email btw.

Comment: Why not normalize the emails then?  Just remove the periods, etc... then compare the resulting strings for equality?

Comment: the problem isnt how to determine whether the two emails are equal given the rules, its what are the rules. i gave a few examples, but those are only the ones i noticed empirically.

Comment: There are no rules because people can and do have identical emails that differ only by digits.  Yahoo offers those as a suggestion when one tries for an email address that's taken.  If you're doing this, then you're basically betting that statistically, this won't happen in your data.  If that's the case, just nix all punctuation and digits and compare the results.

Comment: No, you're completely missing the issue: its the same account, it goes to the same email box, it is just 2 different representations of the same email.