# Gmail username collapsing

Tags: email, gmail

I noticed that the following gmail addresses are equivalent: foo@gmail.com and f.oo@gmail.com, and I would like to collapse these equivalent email addresses in a single category. I searched on the Internet about the gmail collapsing rules, but I didn't find anything. Do you have any idea of how can I normalize the gmail addresses?

P.S. By equivalent I mean that if I send an email to f.oo@gmail.com, then I will receive it in my mailbox, i.e. foo@gmail.com.

P.P.S. I think that somebody asked for the same question here: [What emails are equivalent to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461279/what-emails-are-equivalent-to-each-other), but no correct answer was given. Maybe I should close this thread?

Comment: if the domain is gmail then f.oo is equivalent to fo.o and to foo. So basically you just have to drop the dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GMail rules work like this:

- Case is ignored.
- Dots are ignored.
- A plus character and anything following it is ignored.

You could thus normalize GMail usernames by first lowercasing the string, then removing all dots, then truncating the string right before the first plus character.

Note that these rules are specific to GMail. (Ignoring case in usernames is fairly universal but apparently not required by the relevant standards.)

Users may be angry if you send them email at "stripped" addresses. If someone gives you the address joe+yourapp@gmail.com, that's generally because they want to be able to filter the output from your application. If you then send mail to joe@gmail.com, you're sort of going against the user's explicit wishes.

Comment: OK, thank you! How can I find more about the rules of other email providers, such as yahoo and hotmail? Do they follow the same pattern?

Comment: I don't know -- I think you'll just have to search around the web. I'd wager most email providers don't even formally specify this. The only reason it's fairly easy to find for GMail is because it's so wildly popular. The one thing that's done near-universally is to ignore case (see edit).